# Z3 array: why Select() does not return value saved by Store()?

Tags: z3, smt

I have simple Z3 python code like below. I expect the "print" line will return me "y" which was stored in the line above it. Instead, I got back "A[x]" as result.

```python
I = IntSort()
A = Array('A', I, I)
x = Int('x')
y = Int('y')
Store(A, x, y)
print Select(A,x)
```

Why does not `Select()` return the value stored by `Store()`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things to note:

First:
When you write

```
Store(A, x, y)
```

You create a *term* with three arguments , A, x, and y. 
There is no side-effect to A.
You can create a name for this term by writing

```
B = Store(A,x,y)
```

Second:
Z3 does not simplify terms unless you want it to.
The python API exposes a simplification function called simplify.
You can obtain the reduced term by calling the simplifier.
The example is:

```
I = IntSort()
A = Array('A', I, I)
x = Int('x')
y = Int('y')
B = Store(A, x, y)
print Select(B,x)
print simplify (Select(B,x))
```

Comment: Nikolaj, this is awesome, thanks! However, I am really curious about the simplify() of Z3. It seems it can do some "optimization", but how well that does? Any comparison with the optimization done by the compiler? Any documentation/paper on how the simplify works internally? Thanks!

Comment: The `simplify` is just a bottom-up rewriter. We do not have a paper describing it because it is based on well-known techniques. I also assume it is far simpler than intermediate code optimizations applied by compilers such as gcc. You can find its implementation in the directory `src/ast/rewriter` in the Z3 code base (http://z3.codeplex.com). The array simplification rules are implemented in the file http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/2a286541e002#src/ast/rewriter/array_rewriter.cpp